# Creating a conf file for a web server

Tags: mysql, adminer

For my web database I am trying to create a webserver so I need to make a conf file. When I try to edit my conf file and save it wont let me and says permission denied. I have already given myself read and write access, but I still don't have access to the edit the file. Here is the link to the resource I am using to set up my webserver : https://github.com/orsenthil/adminer-on-mac

Comment: Oh and one more thing, at the end of the document that I linked it says to edit hosts under the etc directory, but when I try to access hosts my terminal says that hosts is not a directory

Comment: Unfortunately, webserver-related questions are off-topic here.  Check the [on-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) item in the help center for more info.

Comment: Okay will do, thank you

Comment: Is this related to sql-server, or are you using adminer with another RDMS (MySQL, SQLLite, Oracle, Postgres)?

Comment: I am trying to use adminer with mySQL @scsimon

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with local web servers and mysql on Mac for over 15 years, so this recommendation is coming from that experience.

OS X updates will destroy your local web development environment every time you do a major OS update... Don't use the built in Apache, PHP and MySQL. Use Homebrew to install independent web server components.

Now to your problems:

`/etc/hosts` is a file not a directory. Each line is a separate record. The line they gave `127.0.0.1 apache.local` just means that your local computer will be accessible from `http://apache.local`. This hosts file can be used to avoid DNS lookups for any website.

The conf file you are referring to is the Apache VirtualHost file? OS X is very protective about files in `etc`. Have you tried sudo? If you change the permissions to your user, Apache may not be able to function.